# How to dynamically change the field order of a class in FileHelpers

Tags: c#, filehelpers

On a daily basis - I need to process 5 files in a c# application using the FileHelpers library. Each file comes from a different client.

The files all represent the same entity - so I have an "Individual" class in my program that contains all the fields and I need to load the data from the files into this object. (the files are delimited files)

The problem is that each file arrives with it's columns in it's own order.
So: 
Client 1 sends: Name, Surname, SSN, Age
Client 2 sends: Name, Age, Surname, SSN
Client 3 sends: Name,  SSN ,Surname (age is optional - so this client doesn't send it)

I'd really like to handle this using a single class and not create one class for each client - since my client base will hopefully grow :-)

Does anyone have any clever ideas for handling this situation with FileHelpers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solutions could be to insert a header row with field name for each csv file and manage it in your class

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would instead strongly push for any one of these approaches:

a) Mandate the field order (and exact specification of each column data type, uniqueness etc.) New clients use the prescribed format, and you encourage old clients to switch when they make other changes to their export.

b) Get your clients to switch to a format you specify where field order doesn't matter, e.g. JSON or XML. Sell it with e.g. "it allows more features".

c) If a) & b) are unworkable, do use multiple classes where needed, as pre-processing before converting to your own internal class. If you can't mandate field order to your clients, it's very likely that other things than field order will also differ at some point, so you will end up doing client specific processing anyway. Still use as *few* classes as possible, maybe some clients could use the same order & content.

My 0.02SKr worth (being Swedish :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DelimitedClassBuilder`and build you record class in code.

```
string[] columns; // populate this somehow: e.g., read the header.

// create the FileHelpers record class
// alternatively there is a 'FixedClassBuilder'
DelimitedClassBuilder cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("Customers", ","); 
cb.IgnoreFirstLines = 1; 
cb.IgnoreEmptyLines = true; 

// populate the fields based on the columns
foreach (string column in columns)
{
     cb.AddField(column, typeof(string)); 
     cb.LastField.TrimMode = TrimMode.Both;
}

// load the dynamically created class into a FileHelpers engine
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());

// import your records
DataTable dt = engine.ReadFileAsDT("testCustomers.txt");
```